# How can I put a string character before Console.ReadLine() Console application

Tags: c#, console.writeline, console.readline

I want to put a character before the user input, like in the regular cmd. I tried 
`Console.WriteLine("]", input = Console.ReadLine())` where input is the string that gets the user input, but it does not work. I also tried something on the lines of `Console.WriteLine("]" + input = Console.ReadLine());` but this returned me the error 'The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer'.

Comment: `Console.Write("]"); input = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: The difference is, `WriteLine()` adds a newline character to the end of the line. `Write()` does not.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Console.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hebffx2d.aspx) instead of [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb.aspx) to read the input from same line

```
Console.Write("]"); // does not insert new line after ]
input = Console.ReadLine();
```